# Label not aligning with other input or labels

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors, label

Newbie here. I am trying to come up with a simple one-page site but my contact form first name label is not attaching with the correct section.

I am attaching the image where the underlined "First Name" is not with the input, even though I have added it under another section and container.

[image]

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sitemize Hoşgeldiniz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <section id="information">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="information-showcase">
                <h1 id="header"><span id="header-span">Sitemize</span> Hoşgeldiniz</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="short-info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-image-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <h2>Anında Sipariş</h2>
                        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <h2>Hızlı Teslimat</h2>
                        <i class="fas fa-truck fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <h2>Mmnuniyet Garantisi</h2>
                        <i class="fas fa-smile-beam fa-5x"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="contact-us">
        <div class="container">
            <form action="#">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                <label for="fname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
            
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
/* Body */
body {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0A800C
  }

.nav-items {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.nav-items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-items a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

/* Image section */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#information {
    background:url("resim2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 400px;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.lead {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: center;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.row {
  margin-left:150px;
}
```

Thank you
Onur

Comment: Add the `form` CSS please

Comment: what exactly I am to do this the form?

Comment: add the form css: display: inline-block;

Comment: use position : absolute ;

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/css-layout-properties/pt/css-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are using the

```
float
```

in your css that is makeing the problem

if you need your elements to be horizantly

add this to .row

```
.row {
 margin-left: 150px;

 display:flex;
}
```

remove this property from your css

.column

and wrap the items with a div that has this property

`display:flex;`

you can learn more about it here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYq5PXgSsbE

good luck!

look how i did it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qjmbgj?file=index.html

https://js-qjmbgj.stackblitz.io

if you cant use display flex

use position :absolute ;

for more understanding

go here

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/css-layout-properties/pt/css-position

Comment: Thanks for your help however I can not use flex or grid for this project, I am allowed to use only basic css.

Comment: display :flex ; is a basic css

Comment: .row {
 margin-left: 150px;

 display:flex;
}

Comment: i added some links to the answer look around and check display flex it is amazing

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qjmbgj?file=index.html

https://js-qjmbgj.stackblitz.io

Comment: no I know but IE does not support Flex and we need this site to be accessible from all platforms :/

Comment: so the only way you will able to make your site works is by applying float also for the label ,  but I may suggest that you ask him if he meant  IE or microsoft Edge ? because it is weird to have a assignment to give to an old browser

Comment: you can also use position: absolute ;

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css/css-layout-properties/pt/css-position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224657/discussion-between---and-onur-karadeniz).

Comment: Hey man I wanted to thank you for that web sites as well it helps me understand the positioning very well :) תודה